# How to restore parameter info (argument list) shortcut with Resharper?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, resharper, visual-studio-2013

Every IDE I know of, including Visual Studio, uses `ctrl+shift+space` to show information about the parameters to a function.  Unfortunately, when you install Resharper, it maps that to `ctrl+p` instead.

**How can I change it back to `ctrl+shift+space`?**  Every setting I see under Environment --> Keyboard doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you go to the Visual Studio Tools -> Options -> Keyboard section, you can type the shortcut in the shortcut keys edit box and VS will show what commands are bound to that shortcut combination. So, hitting `ctrl+shift+space` will show you that is mapped to "Edit.ParameterInfo" for the Workfow Designer, and "ReSharper.ReSharper_CompleteCodeSmart" for the Text Editor and the XAML UI Designer. You can do a similar thing with `ctrl+p`.

You can also remove or assign shortcuts by finding the command name in the list first, and hitting remove, or assign.

Comment: As I mentioned in the question, I already looked there.  However, I must have missed it the first time; the shortcut I was looking for was "Resharper.Resharper_ParameterInfo_Show".  Thanks anyways!